# What is the minimum value of $f_\infty=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt[4]{x-\cdots}}}}$?

Tags: limits, functions, recursion, maxima-minima, nested-radicals

In a similar vein to [What is the maximum value of this nested radical?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062908/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-this-nested-radical), I'd like to share a similar nested radical, but this time with changing fractional powers.

> What is the minimum value of $$f_\infty=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt[4]{x-\cdots}}}}$$ where the radicals go up by one each time?

- Here is a plot of $f_{19}$. We can see that as $x\to 1^+$, $\min f_{19}\to 1.7186$ which is strange as the denominator can only take the binary values $0$ or $1$ at $x=1$. The curve is monotonically increasing from $1$ onwards, which is expected as the numerator dominates.

[image]

- Actually, a simulation in PARI/GP up to $f_{100}$ yields a minimum value of around $1.718565$, which is somewhat close to $e-1$, although I strongly doubt that it will ever reach that value.
- Note that $f_k$ is defined in $(1,\infty)$ for all positive integers $k$, but the curve swings wildly for $(-\infty,1)$. It is, of course, not a good idea to differentiate $f_\infty$ directly, but unfortunately we can't take $x$ and $\sqrt{x-\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt[4]{x-\cdots}}}$ separately as both are increasing.

> **Another interesting question:** Why is the minimum value of $f_k$ for large $k$ not equal to the expected $0,1$ or $\pm\infty$? Is it possible to manipulate $f_\infty$ so that L'Hopital can be used to find the value of $1.718\cdots$?

Related are

- [Evaluating the limit of $\sqrt[2]{2+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{2}}}}$ when $n\to\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837189/evaluating-the-limit-of-sqrt22-sqrt32-sqrt42-cdots-sqrtn2?rq=1)
- [Find $\sqrt{4+\sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[4]{4+\sqrt[5]{4+\cdots}}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782032/find-sqrt4-sqrt34-sqrt44-sqrt54)

but neither have been solved as of now.

Comment: L'Hospital cannot be used since for $x\rightarrow 1$, the numerator tends to $1$.

Comment: @Peter I know, I was wondering if we can write $f_\infty$ in a different way so that both numerator and denominator are $0$ or $\infty$.

Comment: The denominator tends to $$0.581880523059785627121\cdots$$ for $x\rightarrow 1$

Comment: I sincerely doubt the minimum has a nice expression. The increasing roots are going to ensure that.